Can the establishment of a space colony crater land in a healthy economy?
The setting is a prosperous entrepot city whose economy is booming, and hasn't had an economic crisis in living memory. However, it also has these vast tracts of empty land that have been abandoned decades ago, with the skyscrapers and other buildings slowly falling into ruin. Few people live here anymore, all services have been switched off. It's mostly just a residence for criminals, the homeless, and other low lives.
The cause is supposed to be that Earth has finally established extraterrestrial colonies, and it has led to a massive exodus of wannabe settlers that want to make their own countries. Consider it analogous to the settlement of the New World.
Anyways, my plan was that it has crashed property prices due to excess supply of free land on other planets. So there are massive empty tracts of land that once used to be bustling metropolitan areas. And it's been long enough that most of the elderly retirees have died off.
Does that make sense? Am I missing something?

If the city is prosperous and had not had an economic crisis in living memory then why are they tolerating ruined skyscrapers and other buildings, and especially areas which are just a residence for criminals, the homeless, and other low lives? Any self-respecting prosperous city would have demolished the buildings and redeveloped the areas, or converted them into parks and recreational spaces, or whatever.

I would suggest having a technology- and infrastructure-driven total economic collapse of one part of the city's ecosystem. For instance: it is a seaport. Suddenly it's cheaper to ship freight to and from the moon with the orbital launchers hundreds of km away than it is to ship freight between Eastport and Westport across the Pacific. Eastport's financial and entertainment sectors are booming like never before, but the shipping industry is toast and everybody who was part of it has moved out.

Using Detroit as a (partial) template. Part of that cities long term recovery plan is the consolidation of its declining population into areas judged to have the best transport links, retail & service outlets as well as other factors that make them more livable and economically self sustaining.  Then abandoned houses/streets are leveled & anything useful recycled. If your future city is so prosperous it would have started knocking down all the abandoned buildings & streets etc long ago. Then they'd just turn the best cleared areas into urban green space etc while rewilding everything else.

Remember that colonies of any kind are not economically viable for some time. It takes a lot of investment and the ability to pull resources and food from the surrounding area to make a colony viable.


city whose economy is booming, and hasn't had an economic crisis in living memory


it has crashed property prices due to excess supply of free land on other planets.

It will be hard to concile these two: whoever has put money in properties before the crash will see their capital vaporising with the crash, and that is bound to have consequences on the economy. The government might play the card "post bubble Japan", allowing to write properties at their purchase value in balance sheets, but that would just keep the crisis stay longer.

But the money from other sources more than cancels it out, multiple times over. Wealth per person, for example, is much higher than before. So are living standards.

My original (and more likely) answer is below. Here is the world building one:
Your city is still a port city due to its location, but because of its existing infrastructure it was also a good location for a space port.
Over time, the goods that arrived in your city were no longer shipped to another location on earth, but to a colony. Additionally, there was a healthy manufacturing industry, but automation and lack of labor have caused its decline. Fortunately, because of its new role as a space port, the city's economy slowly transitioned over.
Now, old factories and housing for workers are empty and in disrepair. The city has no need for the land and focuses on spaceport infrastructure and temporary housing for people passing through.
Original: Detroit
For various economic reasons, Detroit fits your bill. Massive areas deserted. Warehouses, buildings, and development zones left in decay. You would be hard pressed to find a city with empty buildings and neglected land that was not victim of an economic crisis.
The rise and fall of Detroit

The question is about "a prosperous entrepot city  [which] hasn't had an economic crisis in living memory". That's not Detroit.

@AlexP Bypassing the obvious incongruity in OPs question, you could say Detroit in 1970s so that the obvious crisis hasn't happened yet. But anything that leaves empty buildings will manifest itself as an economic crisis.

The settlement of the New World was not an easy thing to do. A number of attempted colonies failed. Many Europeans who came to the Americas died within a year. The cost of getting people to the New World was large. The US had lots and lots of European investment in order to make it into a successful country.
Free land on other planets has to be balanced against the cost of getting to that "free land" and the people you want to go there have to have the belief that land is the future of wealth and prosperity. Once there, they have to contend with the challenges of making that land grow food and generate enough wealth to pay off the loans they took on to get there. Often, they come with preconceived ideas of what farming will work and starve while learning what actually works.
An alternative idea instead of everyone leaving for "free land", have the investors pull out of the existing colony which stops the shipments of new goods to the place. People are struggling because most things they thought would work don't. The folks with any money went back to Earth and abandoned their buildings. To be a successful city without constant investment from Earth requires that the city be able to generate enough food to feed everyone and to create enough trade goods / services to pay for anything they import from Earth (including the transportation costs).

I think the obvious answer is in population decline. The Space Colonization not only siphoned away the young and the ambitious, but also skyrocketed the automation of every service and industry.
Thus, your city is prosperous from the space income, but it has 1/10 of the population it used to have. There is nobody to live in these buildings, and no reason to redevelop the land into parks, recreation or service buildings, because there is nobody to use them. The Portside of the city became a hub of commerce, surrounded by gentrified housing for the elderly urbanites who refused to go to space (but ivested in the space race and are now living off the profits), and the few of their grandkids who found good employment at the space-port itself and the related services. The tiny number of the homeless and criminals who live in the ruins are those who, for one reason or another, failed to catch the tails of the Space Race and get rich.
Land and property only holds value if there are actual people to use them.

Convoluted Property abandonment law
So, if I understand your question correctly - you are asking if it is feasible for a a city with a main primary source of revenue (A Port in this case) to remain economically active, whilst having large amounts of abandoned buildings around it.
I believe the answer can be Yes.
Now, generally - as an area becomes economically stimulated, you get complimentary businesses spring up.
Consider a Wild West frontier town - Gold is found, the Town now has a primary industry (Mining).
You need a Blacksmith for tools, a clothing maker for clothes or repairs. A Hotel or temporary lodging for the inevitable influx of workers. A Saloon, A Brothel etc.
All of these businesses are there to support the needs of the mine workers. In-fact, you can see modern day variants of this in parts of Australia with remote mining towns.
They also help with Money Velocity (how quickly money changes hands) - which is why I raised Brothels - regardless of your moral views on the occupation, there is a fair amount of data that these were vital in the economies of Mining towns for the above reason. On average Men and Women have different spending habits (most consumer spending is done by Women, whereas Men tend to buy big things) - which, in turn, supported other more reputable businesses.
Then as the economy continued to grow, more people would be attracted etc. and then you get niche businesses that can only exist with a sufficient population size to support them.
Now with a preamble done, let us address your question
The above is necessary to give an idea of how an Economy works - generally when people move away, the economy shrinks and then businesses close as there is less money circulating to support the additional services.
However, if we assume that the main industry (the Port) is not only still healthy, but is in fact growing with additional trade, then it is reasonable to say that this would offset the decrease in money velocity caused by people leaving.
Thus the people that are left are still doing well. Especially if many of the typically associated complimentary services have been taken elsewhere
(this is the first part of your question dealt with)
Now - the next part as to why there would be abandoned land - If we assume that before this, Space was at a premium and the more valuable something is, the more complex the surrounding Case Law is likely to be. So there are all sorts of rules around abandoned land and how it can be reclaimed and it is so extensive that disputes can take decades to resolve - thus the area around the city is left mostly as-is.
For a somewhat real-world example of this: Waiwera hotpools in New Zealand:
Here Auckland is the biggest city in NZ, Thriving economy - yet Waiwera (a once treasured pool complex, many happy memories there) was bought out, then some funny stuff happened and it has been falling to dereliction since.

Yeah, that makes sense if the details are right.
Prices can be kept artificially high by landlords and government for a while, but not indefinitely. Eventually they will crash if no one wants to live there, or it will just fill up with squatters and slowly self-destruct.
Plenty of ghost towns and cities around the World that are just abandoned for various reasons.

The question says that the city is prosperous and had not had an economic crisis in living memory. This definitely excludes ghost towns.

@AlexP It seems you misunderstood the answer
